# Countably Saturated Models

Tags: model-theory

[image]

I’m struggling to get an intuition on the non-existence of countably saturated models for complete theories with uncountably many types... I know many people on here seem to abhor the “why?” question, but I can’t help but ask why is this the case, in order to fully understand the issue.

Comment: I think you mean "*un*countably many types" ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes good catch

Comment: This is a very good "why?" question! I think what people really abhor is posting an image instead of typing out the text, and failing to give a reference to what source you're reading. :0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is an example in an infinite language; it's not hard to modify it to work in a finite language.

*Actually, barring further context there's a serious typo in the text. All complete theories have countably saturated models; what's true is that we don't always have **countable** countably saturated models.*

*Interestingly, the existence of **fully** saturated models of any cardinality of arbitrary complete theories is independent of the usual axioms of set theory!*

---

For $i\in\mathbb{N}$ let $U_i$ be a unary relation symbol. For $A,B$ disjoint finite sets of natural numbers, let $$\psi_{A,B}\equiv\exists x[\bigwedge_{a\in A}U_a(x)]\wedge[\bigwedge_{b\in B}\neg U_b(x)].$$ Let $$T=\{\psi_{A,B}: A,B\mbox{ disjoint finite sets of naturals}\}.$$

Intuitively, a model of $T$ amounts to a bunch of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, possibly with repetition *(and conversely, a multiset of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ yields a model of $T$ precisely when it is appropriately "dense" in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$)*.

If $M\models T$ is countably saturated, then for each $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ there must be some $c\in M$ such that for all $i$ we have $M\models U_i(c)$ iff $i\in S$. But this means that no model of $T$ with cardinality $<2^{\aleph_0}$ is countably saturated.

(It's not hard to modify the above to use only a finite language.)

---

In general, the point is that a structure's cardinality can't be smaller than the number of distinct types realized in it (trivially), and reasonably saturated models have to realize lots of types.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!